# Error on heroku deployment in Rails + Angular. ui-router

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, angular-ui-router, angularjs-injector

Rails backend. Angular frontend. Using angular-ui-router. On the local, it works fine. But when it is deployed on heroku, it gives this error. All dependencies seem to be downloaded properly. I need help seeing what this error indicates.

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular/angular
//= require angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router

//= require bootstrap
//= require_self
//= require_tree .

angular
  .module('maphack', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        component: 'homePage'
      })

    // default fall back route
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    // enable HTML5 Mode for SEO
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
});
```

Error Message on Console:

```
application-118d41a….js:4 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to 
instantiate module XXXXX due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: t
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/unpr?p0=t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the culprit is JavaScript minification. Angular's modules injected this way usually are obfuscated by a JavaScript compressor.

One possible solution is to use another syntax while declaring dependencies. Change this:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
```

to this:

```
.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider]) {
```

The latter is not vulnerable to JS minification as you're declaring the dependencies in strings, and Angular is smart enough to pick those and inject in your config.

[Ready to learn more?](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to deploy on heroku, and it is saying Syntax error.

Comment: @SWKING - Please update your question with error log.